# Proof that space of correlation matrices is compact

Tags: matrices, compactness, correlation

An $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix is a correlation matrix, if it is positive-semidefinite and all its diagonal entries equal 1. According to most references it is easy to see that the space of correlation matrices is both convex and compact. How?

Comment: A correlation matrix is a continuous transform of a vector in the unit hypercube of $\mathbb{R}^{n(n-1}/2}$, constrained by the determinantal positivity condition.